# angular object post to laravel db

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, laravel

I have a json formatted post that arrives in the laravel api controller :

```
public function update($id) {
    $post=Request::all();

    return $post;
}
```

the post logs out to the console:

```
{id: 1, title: "Quiz1", description: "This is a quiz", level_id: 1, questions: Array[2]}
```

I would like to use the $post data in the laravel api controller to extract the data from the json object array and update my database.

The angular post is:

```
$scope.updateQuiz = function(quiz) {
$scope.loading = true;

$http.put('/admin/api/quiz/' + quiz.id, {
 quiz
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  $scope = data;
  console.log($scope.quiz);
    $scope.loading = false;

});
```

};

The code works in that it grabs the angular data and posts it to Laravel function and then posts back to the console in the angular app.

It is just the extraction of individual data that I cannot do.

This seems to work for individual posts but is rather cumbersome:
Angular:

```
$http.put('/admin/api/quiz/' + quiz.id, {
    title:quiz.title
 }).success......
```

Laravel Api:

```
 $quiz->title = Request::input('title');
```

Wondering how I can avoid listing out all post objects.Must be something obvious I'm missing!?

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't shown up the code you tried in your PHP controller.

Comment: I won't confuse the situation with that. Simply how can I extract any date form the $post object, as it is clearly running in and out of the Laravel controller

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```
public function update($id) {
    $post = Post::find($id);

    if( !is_null($post ) ){
        $post->title= $request->input('title');
        $post->description= $request->input('description');
        //And so on for all fields...

        $post->save();
    }
}
```

Note : it's not present in my example above, but you should validate the values received with the laravel validation. See http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation

If your question was about how you redirect the http request to the controller, you should read the routing chapter of the doc : http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing
ex :

```
$app->group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function($group){
    $group->put('/admin/api/quiz/', 'YourController@update');
});
```

Comment: Not sure what you are doing there: why this  $id = $request->input('title');

Comment: As I said the the angular object is posting to the api and picking it up in the Request:all(); and returning it back to the console from there. So none of the above are the issue.

Comment: If you look at my code in the controller, I extract the values from the json, and save the model (update), so I think it does what you asked for... If not, I don't get what you're asking for

Comment: You can't do a $request without Request $request as an update parameter, even then it creates an internal 500 in the console post back and doesn't update the database.